# react-native run-ios crashes after "bundle" phase of metro bundler

Tags: react-native

I'm new to RN and trying to debug why the app crashes with no error message.  The splash screen comes up, then the green bar on top, then it crashes.  There's no message in the metro terminal. The app runs fine if i run it directly from xcode.
Are there some error logs somewhere else?